# Component with routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to do some functionality in CountriesHoc, but my code doesn`t work. Can anyone explain me why?

It doesn`t work

App

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='countries'>
    <CountriesHoc/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

CountriesHoc

```
<>
  <Route path='known' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={learnedCountries}/>}/>
  <Route path='unknown' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={notLearnedCountries}/>}/>
  <Route path='all' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={allCountries}/>}/>
</>
```

Errors:

[image]

=================================================================================

It works

App

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='countries'>
    <Route path='known' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={learnedCountries}/>}/>
    <Route path='unknown' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={notLearnedCountries}/>}/>
    <Route path='all' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={allCountries}/>}/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: What is wrong with using the working code? It's more succinct and works.

Comment: @DrewReese, my app will rerender many times, it's just a piece of code

Comment: Wouldn't the app rerender many times either way? I'm just trying to understand the impetus for factoring the nested routes into a wrapper component that requires another `Routes` component. I'm wondering if there was some underlying issue you think is fixed by using a wrapper component.

Comment: @DrewReese In CountriesHoc i have useEffect which do request, needs only in this component. So no sense to do request in App component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to this wrap your routes inside of Routes component of Router-dom

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='known' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={learnedCountries}/>}/>
  <Route path='unknown' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray= 
  {notLearnedCountries}/>}/>
  <Route path='all' element={<CountriesPage filteredArray={allCountries}/>}/>
<Routes/>
```

and also change the parent to

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='countries/*' element={<CountriesHoc/>}/>
</Routes>
```

you can also add an index boolean prop on the first route in your child component to have a default component for getting showed note that it should be without path prop

UPD: added '/*'

Answer (score -1):

Route contains component props

That will render the component that needs to be displayed

App

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='countries' component={CountriesHoc}/>
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes> 
 <Route path='countries' component={<CountriesHoc/>}/> 
</Routes>
```

Comment: Already tried to do it

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home} from './Pages'


<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes> 
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> 
        </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Already did it.

Comment: Good work, go head ☺